Fontawesome 6 hosted locally not showing icons
I am trying to host font awesome locally, though it doesn't show its icons and I have no idea why.
Here is what I did:
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset = UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="resources/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawsome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawsome/css/brands.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawsome/css/solid.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
    ...
</body>

And here are the files I added to my project:
Font awesome files I added to my project
I tried looking on https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts but it doesn't say to do anything different. I expected the fontawesome icon would be shown

Make sure your folder name is actually fontawsome, not fontawesome.

@mrconcerned Or the other way round, you know. Changing it to fontawesome in the code :)

You are inconsistent in your usage of the closing slash on your tags. Not a fix but you should remove them because no HTML specification requires them and they do nothing and browsers ignore them.

Oof, yeah, it was a typo. Not in the folder name: in the file name. I'll add an answer

Oof, it was a typo in the file name. Sorry guys, thanks for the attention. I wrote font-awesome.min.css instead of fontawesome.min.css
